# Polygon-shaped image in tensorflow and keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am training two different custom-built Unets using Keras and, in principle, they work well. But they are predicting pictures inside a polygon, so I am only interested in a part of the quadratic output image as shown in the example of the figure. I can of course remove the unwanted part of the image after training and prediction using numpy:

image[np.where(mask < 0.5)] = np.nan

But it would surely be better to remove the unwanted part of the picture before training in tensorflow. No need to train anything outside the polygon. Any ideas on how to do that without rewriting the whole Unets?

[image]

Comment: I think it's not possible to not modify U-net because U-net takes images as input, images are natively rectangles, training on groups of rectangles not hexagon.

Comment: I have been speculating whether it would be possible in Tensorflow to mask out only pixels of interest and then convert those to a one-dimensional array during training. Later, after predictions with the trained model, one could convert back to the two-dimensional array inside the polygon. Only thing is that I cannot find a way to mask and convert in Tensorflow? In numpy it would have been easy.